Mocking passport.authenticate behaves inconsistently between tests in Jest
I am trying to test an Express.js route in a Node.js application using Jest, where I mock passport.authenticate. Each test requires a different mock implementation of passport.authenticate, but the mock seems to persist between tests when I run them together. However, when I run each test individually, they work fine.
jest.mock("../../../model/user_group.model");
jest.mock("../../../model/user_credentials.model");

const request = require("supertest");
const MockUserGroup = require("../../../model/user_group.model");
const MockUserCredentials = require("../../../model/user_credentials.model");

const mocked_user = {
  email: "test@test.com",
  password: "hashed_password",
  user_type: "user",
  is_active: 1,
};

describe("GET /admin/users", () => {
  let MockPassport;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    MockPassport = require("passport");

    jest.spyOn(MockPassport, 'initialize').mockReturnValue((req, res, next) => next());
    jest.spyOn(MockPassport, 'use').mockReturnValue(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(MockPassport, 'authenticate');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it("Should return 403 if user is not an admin", async () => {
    MockUserCredentials.readByEmail.mockResolvedValue(mocked_user);
    MockUserGroup.getUserPolicies.mockResolvedValue([]);

    MockPassport.authenticate.mockImplementationOnce((req, res, next) => {
      req.user = { email: mocked_user.email };
      next();
    });

    const app = require("../../../app");
    const response = await request(app)
      .get("/api/v1/admin/users")
      .set("Authorization", "Bearer user_token");
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(403);
  });

  it("Should return 401 if no token is provided", async () => {
    MockPassport.authenticate.mockImplementationOnce((req, res, next) => {
      next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
    });

    const app = require("../../../app");
    const response = await request(app).get("/api/v1/admin/users");
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(401);
  });
});


Problem:

When I run each test individually, everything works as expected. However, when I run them together, the MockPassport.authenticate mock from the first test seems to persist and affects the second test, despite using mockImplementationOnce() for passport.authenticate.
I've tried using jest.clearAllMocks() in beforeEach() and jest.restoreAllMocks() in afterEach(), but it doesn’t seem to reset the mock properly.

Expected Behavior:

I want each test to have its own mock implementation of passport.authenticate.
The first test should mock authenticate to return a user and check for a 403 response.
The second test should mock authenticate to return an "Unauthorized" error and check for a 401 response.

Question:
How can I properly reset passport.authenticate between tests so that the mock implementation is independent for each test? What am I missing in the setup that causes the mock to persist between tests?
